# User-defined Activity themes in Android

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-theme

I'd like to know if it's possible to use user-defined themes for Activities in Android. I'm currently giving users a choice between five themes (defined in the styles.xml file) in one of my applications, but it'd be great if I could offer an additional option of using a user-defined theme with a different background image from the user's SD card.

I'm aiming for Android 3.0+ if that makes any difference. Changing the background image of the layout isn't a valid solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `setBackgroundDrawable()` on the `Window` to change the background of the entire window at runtime from a bitmap you load from external storage.

Comment: I had a feeling I could use the Window of the Activity. You're an angel, Mark!

Comment: @MichellBak: "You're an angel, Mark!" -- no, sorry. The membership dues were rather high, and I am not completely sure that I would meet the eligibility criteria, anyway... :-)